Sealing a metal roof from water
I'm after some advice on water sealing our metal roof. I'm in the process of renovating this space as my workshop, complete with insulating it. But before I start any insulation process I want to make sure I've gotten the water leaks issue fully resolved so I don't ruin my other work; I'd hate to spend the time and money on insulation that could get wet and ruined.
This building has a shed roof with metal roof and walls. As you can see from the photos, there's quite a bit of water staining in the woodwork. I think I'm dealing with a couple of things and wondered about the best way to approach this:

First, where the wall and the roof meet is fairly shabby. I'd like to get this area better sealed up to keep out critters and water. The previous owner seems to have stuffed some insulating material and blocking in the area, but I wondered what else I might do here? One thought I had was to add more blocking around the existing work and filling it with expansion foam. But I don't know if that's a great solution.

Second is the general water staining on the woodwork. I suspect what I'm seeing here is shabby roof work and water coming through from the fasteners. I haven't crawled up to the roof yet to see if there are rubber washers or not, but my hunch would be those are deteriorated or unused. I could go through and replace those, but is there another thing to look for or different approach I should take? I assume it's not worth the effort to try and seal from the inside -- seems to me, water will always find a way.


To clarify, I don't currently intend to insulate the ceiling, just the walls. The two primary goals with the workshop are to 1) seal up from critters and water, and 2) stabilize the temps so I can safely store things in the shop that shouldn't get too warm or cold. (I have a window AC unit I've installed on one of the walls, and a small propane heater I'll be installing to help as well.)
As a final note: the insulation I intend to install is 3/4" foil-backed foam board to ensure an air gap between the metal wall and the insulation's foil. Then plywood over top of the insulation.




Photos from above the roof would be helpful.

FYI, this isn't a lean-to. It's a shed roof.

I own a nearly identical shed. I think mine was build in the 1960s or 70s. It also leaks from the fasteners, which are roofing nails with rubber washers that are failing.
You would need to extract and replace every fastener on the roof with modern ones. They'll need to be slightly thicker or slightly longer than the originals to hold properly.
You seem to have adequate wall overhangs to prevent water entry there. Insulation and siding details are out of scope for this question.
